# Launch Microsoft Word from app

Tags: java, android, ms-word

I am trying to use the Microsoft word app available for android but cant seem to find the Intent options documented

I have a file and wish to open with Word:

```
private void editfile(final String file, final String field) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,"appliction/*");
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This launches Word, but doesn't open the selected file - in fact all the files in my storage are greyed out and not selectable (but can be selected if I run Word outside my app)

Is there an interface guide? anyone with any experience of using?

Comment: "This launches Word" -- no, it launches the Storage Access Framework UI. Try `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_EDIT`, preferably with a proper MIME type. Your existing wildcard MIME type has a typo (`appliction` should be `application`), and using a wildcard MIME type is not really appropriate for `ACTION_VIEW`, `ACTION_EDIT`, etc.

Comment: Yes! the spelling mistake probably quite significant there. 
I've now put in "Intent.ACTION_EDIT" along with "application/doc" and it crashes with an error "No Activity found to handle Intent".
How do I let my application know what activity to use for document editing?

Comment: Apparently, Word does not support `ACTION_EDIT`. Try `ACTION_VIEW`. Or, ask Microsoft.